# SP2013: SP.Result returns 0 when calling get_value()

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom

Maybe it is a very simple fix for this but i have problem with retrieving the m_value from a SP.result.

```
SP.Result {}
m_value:false
__proto__:Object
constructor:function ()
customFromJson:function ()
fromJson:function (a)
get_value:function ()
m_value:0
__proto__:Object
```

When i do get_value() it returns the value 0 and not the m_value false

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-execute the query after got the SP.result object.

just run context.executeQueryAsync and you should be fine.